# How to migrate from SVN to GIT and keep history for moved files from different projects

Tags: git, svn, migration, git-svn

I have the following SVN repository:

```
Repository
  Project A
    trunk
    tags
    branches
  Project B
    trunk
    tags
    branches
```

I'm now trying to migrate Project A from SVN to GIT using `git svn clone`. My problem is that Project A has files which were moved from Project B into Project A. The SVN History follows the move and shows the complete history of these files. The GIT log `git log -C --follow fileA` stops on the commit which moved the file.

Is there a way to migrate the project and keep the history of such moved files? I tried different combinations of `--follow-parent` and `--no-minimize-url` but nothing seems to work.